# how to configure elasticsearch 7.2.0 in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am trying to configure spring boot application with  latest version of elasticsearch with both low level client and high level client ? Can anyone suggest me steps please?

I have already tired different ways but its says:
2019-07-29 13:24:13.148  INFO 7716 --- [][generic][T#4]] o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService      : failed to get local cluster state for {#transport#-1}{sqCZNcXuT2aA3-Klz2yaJg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, disconnecting...

org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [][127.0.0.1:9300][cluster:monitor/state] disconnected

public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

```
 @Bean
 public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true)

            .put("cluster.name", "elasticSearch").build();
    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "deprecation" })
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new 
 TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));

    return client;
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws 
UnknownHostException {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
   }
}
```

it says transport address is added on 9300 but shows disconnected.